# Unable to post html page using php

Tags: javascript, php, html

i am new in php.I am trying to send a html registration page in  php    and want it,s response in another handler.php.But when i lick     submit    button it is not moving or refreshing

```
 **Registration.html**

<html >
<form action="handler.php" method="post"  > 
<label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="" /> <br/><br/>

<label >Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value=""/> <br/><br/>

<input name="Submit" type="button" value="Submit Details" />
</form>
</html>

**handler.php**
<?php
$FirstName=$_REQUEST['firstname'];
$LastName=$_REQUEST['lastname'];

echo 'welcome'.$FirstName;
?>
```

Comment: Seems like you are new in html also..

Answer (score 6):

Change this line

```
<input name="Submit" type="button" value="Submit Details" />
```

To

```
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit Details" />
```

Adding Javascript function

```
<input name="Submit" type="button" value="Submit Details" onclick="submitfunction();"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function submitfunction()
{
   document.getElementById("YOURFORMID").submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sunil, Can i use <script type="text/javascript">
document.forumname.submit();
</script>. What is the benifit of using it...

Comment: Yes but you have to call a function onclick of your button then write this code in that function.If you want i can update my answer.

Comment: Dear sunil, can you write that function , i do not have much idea.If i am using this it simply coming to the handler page..